# Replacing a line of text in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have an ATM and I need to open a text file that contains the account info in the following format:

- Account number
- Last Name
- First Name
- Balance (there would be no blanks but this site wouldn't let me)

The file name is Accountnfomation.txt.

Basically, I need to be able to replace/change the Balance value depending on what the user wants. I know how to find the account number in the text file, but I don't know how to skip the next two lines and edit it. Here is some code I've written:

```
try {
    Scanner Account= new Scanner(new File ("AccountInformation.txt"));
    FileOutputStream Account2= new FileOutputStream ("AccountInformation.txt",true);
    while (Account.hasNextLine()) {
        String nextToken = Account.next();
        if (nextToken.equalsIgnoreCase(MyLoginID)) { //searches for specific match
            // the idea here would to be to edit balance amount 
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. It finds the account number, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: create a new file, rewrite it when you reach the balance line replace it and replace the old file with this

Answer (score 1):

In your problem, it would be nice to get to the line you want to change, change it, and leave everything else the same. Unfortunately a file isn't a collection of lines, it is a collection of bytes. If you want to change "10" to "1000" you need to insert some new bytes, that means everything behind it needs to move down a few bytes (likely four or so, assuming utf8).

In the real world we get around this by not storing data in flat files. Assuming you still want a really simple, file based, human readable, format:

- Use one file per entry. You'll have a directory with a lot of files, but the hard work of rewriting changed files and indexing by file name would be done by the os.
- Use a fixed field width format. Define the width of each field then skip to the data you want. You could access your data like a big array.
- Use a predetermined format with readily available tools for parsing and manipulation. XML and CSV come to mind

Answer (score 0):

Using nio:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
try {

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So according to your format balance would be index 3 (without any empty lines). So you call `lines.set(3, newBalance);`, loop through the lines again, adding them to another `StringBuilder` and store the content in a file using the `toString()` method of the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I think he has all his customers in the file. I wouldn't recommend loading everything into memory.

Comment: I dont care if i have load it all into memory the actual file  is not that big, this is actually a school project